# Get specific values from an array by a form action POST

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble getting specific values from an array. I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
                $item1 = $this->request->post['banner_image'];

        foreach($item1 as $k => $v) 
                    {
                      if($k == 'top' && $v > 0) 
                      {
                       echo $v.' - ';
                      }
                    }
```

I need to get only a few values... such us [top] and [left] for each one .

This is the  var_dump($_POST);

```
array(2) {
  ["pavcontentslider_module"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(11) {
      ["layout_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["position"]=>
      string(9) "slideshow"
      ["status"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sort_order"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["auto_play"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["text_interval"]=>
      string(4) "8000"
      ["width"]=>
      string(4) "1170"
      ["height"]=>
      string(3) "540"
      ["image_navigator"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["navimg_weight"]=>
      string(3) "184"
      ["navimg_height"]=>
      string(2) "81"
    }
  }
  ["banner_image"]=>
  array(6) {
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider3.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "engtesto"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "tossing"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "bounce"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "banner-info1"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "90"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "160"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "660"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "335"
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider7.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "test2"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "engtest2"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(12) "banner-info1"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "91"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "183"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "210"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "432"
        }
      }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider5.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "resrser"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "10"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "29"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "20"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "66"
        }
      }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider6.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "teso"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "27"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "22"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "61"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "66"
        }
      }
    }
    [5]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider8.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(6) "tes6yo"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "20"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "14"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "38"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "57"
        }
      }
    }
    [6]=>
    array(7) {
      ["image"]=>
      string(26) "data/slider/imgslider2.jpg"
      ["link"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["title"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "testo"
        }
      }
      ["effect"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(7) "slideUp"
        }
      }
      ["class"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "banner-info"
        }
      }
      ["top"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "29"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "25"
        }
      }
      ["left"]=>
      array(2) {
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "66"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "47"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `$this->request->post['banner_image'];` instead of just `$_POST['banner_image']`?

Comment: I think that your argument is in a nested array, but I can't quite tell because I don't feel like reading through the garbled mess of a var_dump you have there. Can you get the tabbed out output of that (check the source code of the page)?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer and sorry about the garbled mess of a var_dump i'll try to post the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to have a better look at your results are to first `echo "<pre>";` before you var_dump. That will allow you to see how the array is formatted better. My guess is that the `$key` you're searching for is embedded at a deeper level. If you're still having trouble parsing it yourself try editing your post to allow us to see a better formatted view. It's hard to see but try echoing (without the for loop) `$item1[1]['image']` and see if anything is spit out. I think the values you are interested are actually within `$item1[1]` rather than just `$item1`. Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: hi, thanks fo your answer can you explain how to use the this?  echo "<pre>";

Comment: After you've called the first line of you post, simply insert `echo "<pre>";` on the line before you perform `var_dump($item1);` the pre is an html element that means "pre-formatted" [see here](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/literal.html) or [see it work](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp). It will format the output in a legible way.

Comment: Of course this is assuming that `$item1` actually has any values in it since you mentioned you did a `var_dump` of `$_POST`.

Comment: hey i think i got some results... 

as you suggest me ... this is what i did:

$item2 = $_POST["banner_image"];   
echo $item2[1]['top'][4][0]; 

it works.. thank you very much for your help.